# protocol extension, does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I am creating a framework named `MyFramework` containing `LoginProtocol.swift` which has some default behaviours

```
import UIKit

public protocol LoginProtocol {
    func appBannerImage() -> UIImage?
    func appLogoImage() -> UIImage?
}


extension LoginProtocol {
    func appBannerImage() -> UIImage? {
        return (UIImage(named: "login_new_top")) 
    }

    func appLogoImage() -> UIImage? {
        return (UIImage(named: "appLogo"))

    }
}
```

Next, I am adding a new target to create a demo application named `MyDemoApp` which is using `MyFramework`:

```
import UIKit
import MyFramework

class LoginViewContainer: UIViewController, LoginProtocol {    
    // I think I am fine with defaults method. But actually getting an error
}
```

Currently, I am getting an error from the compiler such as

```
type 'LoginViewContainer does not conform protocol 'LoginProtocol'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this message because with protocol extension,the class does not need to conform the protocols

It would be great if I can get some advices about this issue.Thanks

PS:[this](https://github.com/tranvutuan/MyFramework) is a link for these codes. feel free to look at it.

Comment: Your extension isn't public

Comment: @originaluser2: good catch. appreciate your answer. You save me hours.

Comment: Not technically an answer ;) Happy to help, feel free to delete the question now – unless you feel it would be useful for others in which case I *can* write an actual answer. What's important is that this question doesn't appear 'unresolved' to the outside world.

Comment: I am learning Swift now and it will be great if you can write an actual answer so that other members (like me) can know what is going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your `extension` isn't public – therefore it's not visible outside the module it's defined in, in this case `MyFramework`.

This means that your view controller only knows about the `LoginProtocol` definition (as this *is* public), but not the default implementation. Therefore the compiler complains about the protocol methods not being implemented.

The solution therefore is to simply make the extension public:

```
public extension LoginProtocol {
    func appBannerImage() -> UIImage? {
        return (UIImage(named: "login_new_top")) 
    }

    func appLogoImage() -> UIImage? {
        return (UIImage(named: "appLogo"))

    }
}
```